# How to build GCC CC with old linux kernel headers; buildroot

Tags: cross-compiling, compatibility, embedded-linux, buildroot, uclibc

I am attempting to build a cross compiling toolchain using a buildroot package from '09. Unfortunately, I don't have the luxury of upgrading an existing busybox system on my target platform.

Background:
The target platform runs on an arm926EJ (5TE architecture). It was clearly built with uclibc 0.9.29 libraries.
The kernel linux headers on the platform are 2.6.16

Since I can't upgrade a busybox image from scratch I would like to make separate binaries and upload them through tftp, and execute them through a telnet shell.

I have successfully compiled the most recent buildroot toolchain with 4.5 kernel headers and a 1.0.14 uclibc library. 
After successfully compiling a basic helloworld program and uploading it via tftp to the platform, i was able to execute the program but did not see any output.

Although there may have been some problem with stdout and the telnet terminal, I think its most likely a compatibility problem with the different versions between the uclibc libraries.

The problem:
On my host system i have linux kernel headers from linux version 4.6.3.
In order to remmedy the uclibc compatibility issues noted above, I am attempting to build a new toolchain from an old buildroot package. However early in the compilation I have an error which states:

Makefile:1601: mixed implicit and normal rules:deprecated syntax
CHK include/linux/version.h
HOSTCC scripts/unifdef
scripts/unifdef.c:209:25 error: conflicting types for 'getline'

and so on
After researching a bit online and already expecting it to happen, it seems to be a clash between the differing kernel versions.

I am asking this great community for any ways they can think to solve this problem without having to rebuild a host system using an ancient version of linux. If there are any details that I am missing or not completely understanding, feel free to inform me. I am very open to suggestions.

I've considered building a host system using the old headers in a VM. If that is a good way to go about it, any suggestions for a good distro to use would be cool as well.

Im not against ditching buildroot for a better tool, or building a CC from scratch, but should that be the case I am still concerned about conflicting kernel versions.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: *"The kernel linux headers on the platform are 2.16.6"* -- That's not a valid Linux version number.  Perhaps you mean 2.6.16? *"I am attempting to build a new toolchain from an old buildroot package"* -- Refrain from ambiguous *"old"* and *"new"* adjectives, and use version numbers.

Comment: 2.6.16 is correct, will edit the typo.

Comment: What happens when you statically link your hello world application?

Comment: Good question. Would you suggest linking against the libraries on the platform (which i can download) or would you suggest statically linking against the current library that hasn't produced any results. A big part which I forgot to mention earlier is that I have to edit the binary in a text editor produced by the gcc output, and actually change the name of the uclibc library to match version numbers so that thre platform knows what to use. From 1.0.14 (gcc out) to 0.9.29 (what the platform uses) l. This is unorthodox, and why I believe I was having the initial issue.

Comment: You still haven't clarified what version(s) of Buildroot that you're trying to use.  Is it one of the early versions that predate the 2009 release?  IIRC 2.6.16 dates to about 2006/7.   *"On my host system i have linux kernel headers from linux version 4.6.3."* -- You seem confused about kernel headers.  What does the host headers have to with this issue?  Buildroot should be able to build a toolchain with whatever version of kernel headers for whatever version of uclibC.  *"However early in the compilation I have an error..."* -- Compilation of what, the toolchain or some app?

Comment: The "old" buildroot package I am using is 2009.02. The only other version listed in their archived downloads that I can find is 2005, which predates the uclibc library that exists on my target platform. The initial attempt with the "new" package I used was BR 2016.05. The error I am receiving is displayed when running the makefile for constructing the "old" buildroot toolchain.

Comment: The common solution to your immediate problem is to rename the three(?) instances of `getline` in `toolchain_build_arm/linux-2.6.*/scripts/unifdef.c` to something like `br_getline`.  But you're going to encounter more issues such as **kernel.org** no longer archives the patched kernel versions such as 2.6.20.4.  Also old versions of other packages have since been relocated to different directories, e.g. `uclibc.org/downloads/` to `uclibc.org/downloads/old_releases/`.  These are not difficult issues to fix, but you would need perseverance to remedy each issue as it pops up during the build.